# If 'Destination Rule' on Istio is applied, does load balancing of k8s Service not work?

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, istio

I understand that the k8s Service basically performs Round Robin on Pods.

If I set the weight of the pods using the 'Destination Rule' of the Istio, what happens to RR of the existing k8s Service? Are load balancing rules in k8s Service ignored?

Comment: give it a try and I'm sure you'll find answer

Comment: What you mean by `RR of the existing k8s service`? If you apply destination rule without any configuration nothing gonna change, load balancing will be taken from the k8s. If you add the destination rule configuration, like change the loadBalancer options from `ROUND_ROBIN` ( which is the default one used by k8s) to `RANDOM`, or change the weight, it's just gonna be overwritten by istio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand that the k8s Service basically performs ROUND ROBIN on Pods.`

That's correct. It's explained in the kubernetes documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#proxy-mode-userspace).

---

> If I set the weight of the pods using the 'Destination Rule' of the Istio, what happens to RR of the existing k8s Service? Are load balancing rules in k8s Service ignored?

I couldn't find the exact information how it works, so I will explain how I understand it.

As kubernetes service uses kube-proxy's iptables rules to distribute the requests, I assume that istio destination rule can override it with his own rules, and apply them through envoy sidecar. As all traffic that your mesh services send and receive (data plane traffic) is proxied through Envoy, making it easy to direct and control traffic around your mesh without making any changes to your services.

So if you want to change the default ROUND ROBIN to other algorithm (e.g. LEAST_CONN, RANDOM) you can just configure that in your destination rule [LoadBalancerSettings.SimpleLB](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/#LoadBalancerSettings-SimpleLB). Note that by default the algorithm is also ROUND ROBIN, same as with kubernetes service.

More about it [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/concepts/traffic-management/).

---

Additional resources:

- https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/#Subset
- https://istio.io/latest/docs/concepts/traffic-management/#load-balancing-options